# White stringy growth on garlic

Tags: garlic

Does anyone know what this white stringy growth is on my garlic? It almost resembles cobwebs. When you scrape it away the garlic underneath seems intact and unblemished. I am wondering if it has to be discarded or if it is salvageable. I've tried looking for pictures of mold or fungus online and it doesn't seem to resemble anything I've found. I fear it is **white rot**.

[image]

Comment: If the garlic cleans up, you may not need to care. But it does look like fungus. Good soil has extensive fungus.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can find is Garlic White Rot.

[image]

The article mentions stunted bulbs, stunted plants and yellow stripes on the leaves as well.

> - If your garlic is stunted pull them up right away.
> - Watch for striping leaves or strange looking leaves not growing properly.
> - If your garlic leaves are yellowing prematurely, pull up a bulb and inspect one. Leaves will go yellow towards the last couple of weeks as a sign the garlic is ready to be harvested. Diseased garlic however will all be yellow, you actually want some green leaves when harvesting garlic. Learn more about getting the timing right for harvesting garlic here.

From [White Rot Garlic and other Garlic Diseases](https://www.familyfoodgarden.com/garlic-plant-disease-white-rot/).  I am not associated with the site.